# List iteration - User selected value to pass to servlet

Tags: java, list, jsp, servlets

I have a list of values and a text box for every value in the list. User will enter value in any of the textbox. I want to pass that value to the servlet..i am not sure how to do it..

Consider a list has 10 names..

```
<form action="servlet1" method="post">
<%List names = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0; i<names.size();i++)
{
 out.println(names.get(i));%> <input type="text" name="text1">
<input type="submit" value="uvalue">
<%} %>
</form>
```

If the user enters a value in text box, how can i pass the names.get(i) value to the servlet to which user has entered the value...

Comment: You can use different name for thr input boxes appending the index, and in servlet you can used `request.getParameter("text1")` to get the text box value.

Comment: do u want to pass names.get(i) or entered value of input text1 in servlet?

Comment: @bmt if user enters a value in textbox for names.get(3), i want to pass that names.get(3) to servlet...

Comment: do you want populate dynamically created text box while list is reading right?

Comment: @JavaLearner1  I have added answer. I didnot test it. but u have to do similar things.

Comment: @JavaLearner1 you can `request.getParameterValues("text1")` to get the all text box values, it will returns `String[]` which contains all text box values in same order as the textboxes appears to user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one more field which is hidden. set value of named.get(i) into that element like

```
    for(int i=0; i<names.size();i++)
    {
     out.println(names.get(i));%> <input type="text" name="text1">
<input type="hidden" name="names<%=i%>" value="<%=names.get(i) %>">
    <input type="submit" value="uvalue">
    <%} %>
```

And get value of names{0..names.size legth} in servlet with same loop like i.e. names0,names1,names2...names(names.size). `request.getParameter("names0")`

Comment: `request.getParameter("names")` will return only one value.

Comment: thanks. yeah the name also needs to dynamic in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **drop-down** for your `names` list and one text box for input and can do the work in one form.

Here user can select the name from drop-down list and enter its values in the text box and can submit the form.

At Servlet , take both the values i.e

1. Selected name from drop-down list
2. Value from the text box.

Here is a demo for reference:

```
<form action="servlet1" method="post">
<select name="selective_name">
<%
 List names = new ArrayList();
 for(int i=0; i<names.size();i++)
 {
  out.println("<option value="+names.get(i)+">"+names.get(i)+"</option>");
 } 
%>
</select>
 <input type="text" name="text1">
<input type="submit" value="uvalue">

</form>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the all textbox values by using `request.getParameterValues(form_field_name)`, which returns `String[]` of values and if you also want to pass the `names.get(i)` to the server we can have a hidden field for that.

Find the below code:

```
<form action="servlet1" method="post">
<%List names = new ArrayList();
   for(int i=0; i<names.size();i++) {
     out.println(names.get(i));
%> 
     <input type="text" name="textvalues">
     <input type="hidden" name="namevalues" value="<%=names.get(i)%>">
<%} %>
    <input type="submit" value="uvalue">
</form>
```

To get the values from server side:

```
//to get the textbox values.
String[] textvalues = request.getParameterValues("textvalues");

// to get the name values.
String[] namevalues = request.getParameterValues("namevalues");

// index value to access the name values
int index = 0;

for (String textvalue: textvalues) {
    System.out.println("name : "+namevalues[index]+" --> value : "+textvalue);
    index++; // increment to get the next value.
}
```

Give it a try .... :)